# How to access declared variables after a "script" data type AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

First off, thanks for your attention.

I have this variable declared at the top of my script:

```
var declaredVariable = 'test';
```

After, I have this AJAX call:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'example-external.js',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

The requests works. The file **example-external.js** is correctly loaded.

However, inside the file **example-external.js**, I'd like to do this:

```
console.log(declaredVariable);
```

I just need to access a previously declared variable.
But that doesn't work :(

How do I access that variable inside my Javascript file?

Thank you.

---

**Solution!**

I've declared my variable as global:

```
window.declaredVariable = 'test';
```

Instead of:

```
var declaredVariable = 'test';
```

Thanks to **techfoobar**!

Comment: `declaredVariable` will be accessible only inside the *function* it was declared in. To make it accessible elsewhere (globally) you can either drop  the `var` or explicitly do `window.declaredVariable = 'test';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery.getScript() instead

```
$.getScript( 'example-external.js', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
   //done
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful as well, but I think $.getScript can't send post data, is that right? Thank you!